# Problems for starting Ubuntu after i selected on the GRUB? Help!

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I has the problem after select Ubuntu in the GRUB, does not start the operating system and the screen goes black with blinking cursor (_) and so ti is for hours and hours.
I tried to solve it by two ways, the first one, before i select the operating system in the GRUB, I press "e" to edit the commands and I write "nomodeset" instead "quiet splash" and doesn't work (Screen black with blinking cursor). The other one I select Advanced options for Ubuntu, then select Ubuntu, with Linux ... (recovery mode) and nothing. I don't know what to do, please help!

My Computer Model is a Dell Inspiron 3000 Series